# A tree graph with a time line

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I was trying to produce the following graph in LaTex:

[image]

With the following code, I could achieve something similar but not the same:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, sloped]
\node[bag] {X}
    child {
        node[bag] {negative}
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$\beta$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$1-\pi$}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {1}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$\pi$}
            }
            edge from parent
            node[above] {$1-p$}
    }
    child {
        node[bag] {positive}
        child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$R$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$1$}
            }

    edge from parent
            node[above] {$p$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The output is

[image]

Is there a way to add the timeline, and make the lines better aligned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ask you that for new problem ask a new question. Since you rather edit this, I consider edited question as new question which deserve new answer.

One of possibilities to solve your new problem is to add new level to three, remove edges to this level and reduce `l sep` to this level.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{ELS/.style = {% Edge Label Style       % <---
    pos=0.5, sloped, node font=\footnotesize,
    inner sep=2pt, anchor=#1},
        }
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
    font=\sffamily,
% tree
    grow'=0,    % <---
    parent anchor=east,
    child  anchor=west,
% nodes distances
    s sep=8mm,
 where level=2{l sep=3mm}{l sep=12mm},          % <---
% edges
 where level=3{no edge}
              {edge={semithick,line cap=round}},% <---
% edge labels
EL/.style = {% Edge Label
    if n=1{edge label={node[ELS=south]{$#1$}}} 
          {edge label={node[ELS=north]{$#1$}}} 
            },
            }% end for tree
%
[X, name=t0
    [Positive, name=t1, EL=p
        [$R$, name=t2, EL=1
            [good, name=state] % <---
        ]
    ]
    [Negative, EL=1-p
        [$1$, EL=\pi
            [bad]              % <---
        ]
        [$\beta$, EL=1-\pi
            [disaster]         % <---
        ]
    ]
]
\path   (state) node[above=3mm,font=\sffamily] {state} % <---
        (t0 |- state) node[above=3mm] {$t=0$}
        (t1 |- state) node[above=3mm] {$t=1$}
        (t2 |- state) node[above=3mm] {$t=2$};
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Regarding your new demand, to code had to be added aligning at levels. This is can be achieved by option ˙`tier/.option = level` and changes of nodes anchors:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{ELS/.style = {% Edge Label Style       % <---
    pos=0.5, sloped, node font=\footnotesize,
    inner sep=2pt, anchor=#1},
        }
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
    font=\sffamily,
% tree
    grow'=0,    % <---
    anchor=west,
    tier/.option = level,
% nodes distances
    s sep=8mm,
 where level=2{l sep=3mm}{l sep=12mm},
% edge 
 where level=3{no edge}
              {edge={semithick,line cap=round}},
% edge labels
EL/.style = {% Edge Label
    if n=1{edge label={node[ELS=south]{$#1$}}} % <---
          {edge label={node[ELS=north]{$#1$}}} % <---
            },
            }% end for tree
%
[X, name=t0
    [Positive, name=t1, EL=p
        [$R$, name=t2, EL=1
            [good, name=state]
        ]
    ]
    [Negative, EL=1-p
        [$1$, EL=\pi
            [bad]
        ]
        [someverylongword, EL=1-\pi
            [disaster]
        ]
    ]
]
\path   (state |- t2) node[above=3mm] {state}
        (t0 |- t2) node[above=3mm] {$t=0$}
        (t1 |- t2) node[above=3mm] {$t=1$}
        (t2) node[above=3mm] {$t=2$};
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this what you after?

Comment: This works well except that if I replace "$\beta$" with any "longerword", the last column will lose vertical alignment.

Comment: @DavidXiaoyuXu, I ask you to write new question, where you explain what is your problem. See edited answer. Hopefully I correct guess what you after :-)

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:**
Now is added time line:

Like this:

[image]

With `forest` is easy:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
    font=\sffamily,
% tree
    grow=0,
    parent anchor=east,
    child  anchor=west,
    s sep=8mm,
    l sep=12mm,
% edge
    edge={semithick,line cap=round},
% edge labels
EL/.style args={#1/#2}{
    edge label={node [pos=0.5, sloped, inner sep=2pt,
                      font=\footnotesize\sffamily,
                      anchor=#1] {$#2$}}
           }
            }% end for tree
[X, name=t0
    [Negative, EL=south/1-p
        [$\beta$, EL=north/1-\pi] 
        [$1$, EL=south/\pi]
    ]
    [Positive, name=t1, EL=south/p
        [$R$, name=t2, EL=south/1]
    ]
]
\path   (t0 |- t2) node[above=3mm] {$t=0$}
        (t1 |- t2) node[above=3mm] {$t=1$}
        (t2) node[above=3mm] {$t=2$};
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Above elementary use of `forest` can be improved by automatic positioning of edge labels:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{ELS/.style = {% Edge Label Style       % <---
    pos=0.5, sloped, node font=\footnotesize,
    inner sep=2pt, anchor=#1},
        }
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
    font=\sffamily,
% tree
    grow'=0,    % <---
    parent anchor=east,
    child  anchor=west,
    s sep=8mm,
    l sep=12mm,
% edge
    edge={semithick,line cap=round},
% edge labels
EL/.style = {% Edge Label
    if n=1{edge label={node[ELS=south]{$#1$}}} % <---
          {edge label={node[ELS=north]{$#1$}}} % <---
            }
            }% end for tree
%
[X, name=t0
    [Positive, name=t1, EL=p
        [$R$, name=t2, EL=1]
    ]
    [Negative, EL=1-p
        [$1$, EL=\pi]
        [$\beta$, EL=1-\pi]
    ]
]
\path   (t0 |- t2) node[above=3mm] {$t=0$}
        (t1 |- t2) node[above=3mm] {$t=1$}
        (t2) node[above=3mm] {$t=2$};
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Result of above MWE is the same as before.

Comment: This looks great, thanks! One thing that I haven't figured out is how to control the length of each line?

Comment: @DavidXiaoyuXu, lenght of lines are determined by distances of nodes. They are set by `l sep` ("level distance") and by `s sep` ("sibling distance").

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Zarko Would this MWE allow an additional "column" on the right of the "t=2"?  Now connecting line is needed.

Comment: @DavidXiaoyuXu, you can expand shoed tree with new level  nodes or new nodes in levels as well drawn extra/separate lines between nodes. If you have such demand, please explain it in the new question where you show, what you like to achieve. BTW, you may consider to accept answer. As I see. it solve your problem :-)

Comment: How come I forgot to accept this great answer! Thanks for reminding me. I updated the question to reflect the additional column I want. There was a typo in my last comment: it should be "No connecting line is needed"